# Add dimensions to image php

Tags: php, image, height, width

I need to set smaller dimensions as all images are different sizes and need one small size so the page does not stretch, however whenever i add width and height dimensions i keep getting php errors.

Just need width and height for img.

```
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($action)) {
    $output = "<img src=\"../admin/inventory_images/{$res['id']}.jpg\"></img><a href=\"product.php?id={$res['id']}\">{$res['product_name']}</a><br />";
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I don't see any width/height attributes

Comment: Thats the thing, i dont know where to add them whenever i add them i do the formatting wrong and get  syntax error

Comment: Add a class to your `<img>` tag and add the dimensions in your style sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put them in your `<img>` tag as normal:

```
$output = "<img src=\"../admin/inventory_images/{$res['id']}.jpg\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\"><a href=\"product.php?id={$res['id']}\">{$res['product_name']}</a><br />";
```

Comment: ffs i was doing height=\"100" width=\"100" forgetting the other slashes haha so silly sometimes.

Comment: less painfull escapeing `$output = '<img src="../admin/inventory_images/'.{$res['id']}.'.jpg" height="100" width="100"><a href="product.php?id='.{$res['id']}.'">'.{$res['product_name']}.'</a><br />';`

Comment: I would go a step further and use `sprintf()` like I did in their other question

Comment: *Ah,* you see? A repeat customer is a happy customer I always say! ;-) or is that *vice-versa*?

Comment: Good night, why not use PHP concat and stop using the escape characters. Don't know how you read code with fifty slashes everywhere.